# Automatic Top / Middle / Bottom Alignment for 3D Text Object

Tags: python, mesh, workflow, text-object

I think 3D Text object misses basic features like Middle Align and Bottom Align (Currently we have Left, Right, Center, Just and Flush, but they are for horizontal adjustments; The default vertical alignment is Top Align only). Unless I missed something, I'm afraid it is only possible by scripting or driver?

Top Align (Default behavior):

[image]

Bottom Align:

[image]

Middle Align:

[image]

P.S.: I know we have *Offset X/Y* for in-line adjusting (that's what I used to mimic these GIFs), but that's not automatically calculated by line count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to developers, there is a [new feature](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.78/More_Features#Text_Objects) implemented in the upcoming 2.78, which can be the perfect solution here:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are right, aligning the overall text from top/bottom isn't available.

The Left/Right/Centre alter the location of the text relative to each line and allows adjusting the alignment of the text relative to other lines of text.

The up/down alignment only alters the text position relative to the object centre; this can be altered after text entry by moving the text object. Aligning each line left/right can only be done this way if you do one line per text object.

If you think up/down alignment is important, you should suggest it to one of the developers. I doubt this would be considered priority so unless a developer is interested in this you may have more luck in creating a patch yourself and submitting it for review.

Maybe an add-on could be created to add an option for top/middle/bottom alignment.